# Converting from Point datatype to int in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, casting

I am writing a program to move mouse pointer using `SetCursorPos()` defined in windows.h . The parameters to `SetCursorPos` should be `int`. I have `Point` datastructure obtained from a rectangle. How to convert it?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `SetCursorPos(point.x, point.y);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetCursorPos defined as:

```
BOOL WINAPI SetCursorPos(
  _In_  int X,
  _In_  int Y
);
```

So you can use:

```
 Point p;
 ....some code
 SetCursorPos(p.x,p.y);
```